# Author title(s) and affiliation(s)

Tags: publications, authorship, books, titles

What is the correct format to fill out this field in a form? What if the author has no affiliations? Could you please give some examples?

> Author title(s) and affiliation(s):

Comment: I edited the question to include that information.

Answer (score 2):

Author: *Ninja Cat*

Title(s): *Dr*

Affiliation(s): *None*, *unaffiliated*, or https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+affiliation

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm supposed to write it in a single line. 
Would this be correct? "Mr. Ninja Cat, unaffiliated"

Comment: @NinjaCat yes, that's fine.

Answer (score -2):

Affiliation: independent scholar